# Acessing Object Elements

Tags: javascript

When I do

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(chunks1[1].data)))
```

This is the log:

> "{\"data\":{\"0\":0.00006103515625,\"1\":0.00018310546875,\"2\":0.00018310546875,\"3\":0.0001220703125,\"4\":-0.0003662109375,\"5\":-0.000396728515625,\"6\":-0.000518798828125,\"7\":-0.00054931640625,\"8\":-0.00048828125,...

Now can I access the elements of "data"?

If I do

```
chunks1[1].data[0]
```

I get nothing. And

```
chunks1[1].data.1
```

Obviously I will get an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data` is an object. Apart from getting the property with `data.propertyName`, you can also get it using an array notation, specifying the property name as a string. Like this:

```
 chunks1[1].data['0']
```

@aduch makes a good point there. There is another 'data' in the output which I overlooked. The object with the numeric properties is actually a subobject, so the correct notation would be:

```
 chunks1[1].data.data['0']
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `chunks1[1].data.data['0']`?

Comment: I let you get the cookies :D

Comment: Thanks. what you suggest to access to all values of data, and store in array?

Comment: that works to: chunks1[1].data.data[100] (without the ' ' ) so I just have to make an iteration with a for

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are trying to access the elements of data as if it were an array, with numbered indexes, e.g. `chunks1[1].data[0]`.

Instead, because data is an object, you should be using a string index: `chunks1[1].data["0"]`.

And, because in your `console.log` example, `chunks1[1].data` is an object containing data as a key, your final accessing scheme should look like:

```
chunks1[1].data.data["0"]
```